# Display a pdf by using ID in url Javascript/JQuery

Tags: jquery, html, pdf

This is a long shot - i don't have much experience with JavaScript so i thought I come here to see if someone could help.

My problem :

A user receives an email with a link - this link opens a new html page which has been passed a unique ID

e.g. http://www.mysite33.net/work.html?**Id=123456**

From this Id i want to display a pdf on the html page.

The Id references a file which is sorted on a server.

Any advise would be helpful

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're wanting a strictly Javascript approach you can do something like this:

```
<script>

function loadPDF(){

    var match = window.location.search.match(/JobId=([0-9]+)/i);

    if(match){

        window.open('/path/to/' + match[1] + '.pdf');

    }

}

window.onload = loadPDF;

</script>
```

This will search the URL for a JobId argument and if it finds one, will open a pdf with the value as the filename. Make sure to change "/path/to/" to the location of your pdfs.

Comment: This worked - thank you! If I wanted to display the pdf on the html page instead of opening a new page, should i just use <iframe>